# Grails formRemote with jQBootStrapValidator

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, grails

I am working with a simple form that I am submitting via Grails < formRemote > tag. This is working fine and as expected. Recently I added **jqbootstrapvalidaton**.js into my project in order to add some validation on my simple form. When doing this and pressing submit on my form, the form will now POST for **every single element that's defined** (e.g. if I have 5 form elements, I will get 5 POST submissions when I press submit while using Grails's formRemote and jqBootstrapvalidation).

As an example, please consider the following form:

```
<g:formRemote  name="sampleForm" url="[controller: 'test', action: 'demo']" >

<input type="text" name="myy" id="myy" value=""  required />
<input type="text" name="myo" id="myo" value="" required />

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

</g:formRemote>
```

As you can see, the form has 2 input variables and 1 submit button. Typically (when not using **jqbootstrapvalidaton**), I can submit this form and it will POST **one** time to my controller.

However, ever since introducing the **jqbootstrapvalidaton** to this simple form, I am getting 3 POST submissions when I click submit.

The only other code on my page is this:

```
$(function () {
  $("input,select,textarea").not("[type=submit]").jqBootstrapValidation();
}
```

Which I use for setting up the validation.

Has anyone experienced anything similar? Any suggestions as to how to get this form to only POST **one** time, instead of POSTing for each form element would be great!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the jqBootstrapValidation itself to submit your form via ajax.
It has a method to submit the form if there is not any errors.
An sample code is as below:

```
$(function () { $("input,select,textarea").not("[type=submit]").jqBootstrapValidation({

    preventSubmit: false,
     submitSuccess: function (form, event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         dosubmit(form);///your javascript function to submit
     },
     submitError: function (form, event, errors) {
         event.preventDefault();
         }
    }); } );
```